# db with different columns that should store date, however the datatype of one column is date, and the other is varchar, how to do type equality?

Tags: python, postgresql

So im using python and postgresql and I select two things from columns that both contain dates that are formatted yyyy-mm-dd and have that result stored in the array results. However, one of the columns is varchar, and the other one is date. so results would look like [2022-01-10, 2022-01-10]. The type of idx0 is a string, and the type of idx1 is a date object? I have a method that allows me to add any number of days to a certain date, and it works for the varchar one but it doesn't work for the one that is a date object instead of a string. How can I get around this? I'm trying to do if type(results[1]) == date object, or if results[1] isInstace(), but having issues comparing if the type is a certain type pretty much. Can someone show me how to do this? Apologies if this is unclear, i'm happy to explain further.

Comment: adding 2 days to a type date : `SELECT ('2022-01-10' :: date + interval '2 days') :: date`. Result : `2022-01-12`. comparing idx0 as a varchar with idx1 as a date : `SELECT idx0 :: date = idx1`. Adding days to a varchar type is not recommended.

Comment: You need to add the Python code as **text** (no images) update to your question.

Comment: the varchar is created using date object in python though so it will always be formatted properly. im not sure where the danger is there, though i now know its terrible to store a date as a varchar in a database. problem is i did not know that at the time, and everything is built around this flow

Comment: That is still not showing your code. Without  it any suggestions will be guesses.